# Apache aliases are sharing session

Tags: php, apache, session

I have Apache2 on Ubuntu 22.04 with php and mysql. I created two internal websites,
site1 is https://web.domain.cz
and site2 is in same Virtual Host as alias https://web.domain.cz/second (it is some sort of administration for first web)

Here is my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName web.domain.cz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/xxx.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/xxx.key

    <Directory /var/www/web>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Files dbh.php>
        Require all denied
    </Files>

    Alias /second /var/www/second
    <Directory /var/www/second>
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web.domain.cz
    Redirect / https://web.domain.cz/
</VirtualHost>
```

The crazy thing is that when I log out (`session_destroy();`) on one I am logged out on second website. When I change (same) session variable on one, it will change on second (for example I have stored current sorting order in session variable and if I change sorting on one web it will change on second also).

Why are session variables shared and what can I do with it?

(I don't use any framework for PHP)

Comment: Hi, by web do you mean an entirely different browser or the different window of the same browser?

Comment: Hi, they are both different websites. Site1 is `https://web.domain.cz` and site2 is `https://web.domain.cz/second`. But yes I have them open on different tabs on same browser.

Comment: `they are both different websites`...from your point of view yes, but from  the browser's point of view no - `/second` just looks like a subfolder of the same domain, so it'll use the same session cookie

Comment: They are _not_ different sites. I'd recommend actually separating them to different domains, like web.domain.cz and admin.domain.cz, then you'll be able to have a different vhost config for each, and you won't have to worry about whether or not one PHP app can access the assets of the other with a directory traversal.

Answer (score 2):

PHP sessions are based on cookies and cookies are saved by domain by default, since your 2 sites use the same domain, they share the same session.

You can override this behaviour by providing information to distinguish different sites when a session starts, for instance:

```
session_start([
    'cookie_path'=>'second'
]);
```