Isolate PHP sessions of different URL paths with automatic path inference
Let's say I have a service on example.com/index.php and another on example.com/another/path/index.php.
How to isolate both sessions, so that each one cannot use the other one's session?
I tried:
session_set_cookie_params(0, dirname(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));

and
session_set_cookie_params(0, dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));

without success. I see it might be linked with trailing slash but not sure if there aren't other similar caveats.
More generally, which robust way to start a session only for the current URL path?

Does this anwser your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481421/apache-aliases-are-sharing-session/77481595#77481595

No @shingo, because this totally ignore the trailing slash question (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#22458) and similar questions. Also my question is about having the path automatically inferred by PHP, and not hardcoded like in your linked question.

I believe that replacing the hardcoded path with the current path is not difficult, and that could be solved by your another question, right?

You will also need to change the cookie's name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/964287/231316

Personally, I think I'd do this at the server level, which for me is Nginx. I would create a dedicated PHP-FPM pool for each application, and configure things there.

The cookie path needs to match as a prefix of the request path. For any cookie to be available when requesting /index.php, you'd need to set the cookie path to just / - but that will then of course also cover /another/path/index.php. What you want, is not possible when you have such partially overlapping paths.
